# Noty JS заменят пробелы на плюсы. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, cookie, noty

Подключил плагин noty js. Он работает в связке с cookie js. Когда я отправляю cookie в  виде строки в место пробелов появляются плюсы.

```
if (Cookies.get('notice')) {

    new Noty({
        theme: 'limitless',
        layout: 'topRight',
        timeout: 2500,
        text: Cookies.get('notice'),
        type: 'success'
    }).show();

    Cookies.remove('notice', { path: '' })

}
```

`Cookies.get('notice')` содержит строку "Данные сохранены" а на выходе получаю сроку "Данные+сохранены"

Прошу помощи в исправлении ошибки.

Comment: [`.replaceAll('+', ' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.